# How to combine ActiveRecord query results in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My Skill model requires 2 sets of values for business plaubilisation:

1. one comes from attached ValuesList object
2. others come from additional lists of values relating to quality

The models look like this:

```
class Value < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :values_list
end

class ValuesList < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :values, inverse_of: :values_list, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :skills

  # Extra values for missing answer (quality)
  has_many :skills_values_lists, foreign_key: "values_list_id"
  has_many :referents, class_name: "Skill", through: :skills_values_lists
end

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :values_list

  # Extra values for missing answer (quality)
  has_many :skills_values_lists, foreign_key: "skill_id"
  has_many :references, class_name: "ValuesList", through: :skills_values_lists
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skills_values_lists, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Thanks to this, I can query the regular values attached to the skill:

```
@regular_values = @skill.values_list.values
```

(returns an ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy object),

and the extra values coming from several lists of values:

```
@extra_values = @skill.references.map {|vl| vl.values}
```

(returns an array of 1 ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy object).

I'd like to merge these 2 results in one object in order to display the list of all available values in a classical .each loop.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Can't you just merge the extra values into the regular values like this:
`@regular_values = @skill.values_list.values`
`@regular_values.merge(@skill.references.map { |v1| v1.values }`
Or set a new variable that combines both:
`@total_values = @regular_values + @extra_values`

Comment: @Hackman: Thank you for putting me on the way of option 2 of my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer may not be the best, but it solved my problem.

Dealing with 2 types of objects I found out that:

1. adding the array to the collection proxy would try to update the source table =>       `@all_values = @regular_values << @extra_values`
2. adding the collection proxy to the array returns an array of collections with all the data => `@all_values = @extra_values << @regular_values`

Choosing the option 2, I can list the values through a nested loop:

```
      <table class="table table-align-top">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-min-nw"><%= t('Code') %></th>
            <th class="col-min-nw"><%= t('Value') %></th>
            <th><%= t('Description') %></th>
            <th class="col-min-nw"><%= t('UpdatedAt') %></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <% @all_values.each do |value_set| %>
            <% value_set.each do |value| %>
              <tr>
                <td class="no-wrap"><%= value.code %></td>
                <td class="no-wrap"><%= translation_for(value.name_translations) %></td>
                <td class="text-justify text-sm"><%= sanitize translation_for(value.description_translations) %></td>
                <td class="text-right"><%= format_date(value.updated_at) %></td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>

      </table>
```

I hope someone can propose something smarter.

Answer (score 1):

You can rather use a single query to get the values traversing the association between values and values_list, and values_list and skills:

```
Value.joins(values_list: :skills).where(skills: { id: skill_id })
```